# Assign shortcuts to arbitrary windows in order to quickly focus it

Tags: windows, select, focus, shortcut, hotkeys

While programming I enjoy the benefits of a multi-monitor setup using Windows 7. My desktop is usually inhabited by two editor windows, several console windows and a browser (so that I can ask questions on stackoverflow).

Can I somehow assign shortcuts to certain windows in order to quickly focus them? E.g. "Alt+1", "Alt+2" to select the editors and "Alt+3" to select a console?

**Edit:** Forgot to say that each monitor has it's own taskbar.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 7, use the windows key + 1, 2, 3 for the respective windows in the task bar

Comment: Since each monitor has its own taskbar this is not an option. Moreover, I'd rather have the shortcuts independent from the window's position on the taskbar.

Comment: Funny, I have only one taskbar. I think they guys at Microsoft implemented it that way, because now you can lock programs to the taskbar, similar to MacOSX. That way, the order will not change when new windows are opened.

Comment: I am using a 3rd-party tool to get multiple taskbars and I like it a lot.